# What LoRa port do I use to send downlinks to an Eastron SDM630 LoRaWan meter?

Tags: lorawan

I have an Eastron SDM630 LoRaWan meter where the AppEUI, DevEUI, and AppKey have been correctly entered, and where the meter read-out confirms that it is linked to my gateway.

I've been given a link packet to send to the meter so that it will send out its various electrical readings every 30 minutes. However, I wasn't told what LoRa FPort to send it to. I've tried 1 and 125 so far, but I'm not receiving any data being uplinked by the parameter.

Any clues on what the FPort should be to send the downlink?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Can you check with Fport `2` ?
Also check if the Fport number assigned in the GW is same as the fport number used by the end-device.

Please be careful to not assign `0` or `224` as fport because they are reserved.

- 0 is un-assigned.
- 224 is used in compliance mode.